# Alternatives for "broadly applicable"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm giving a presentation, and the content is specific to one particular area. However, the ideas behind the content are applicable to other contexts as well.

What're good alternatives to "broadly applicable" or "applicable elsewhere?"

By the way, it doesn't have to be a single word.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the results are *transferable*

> **Transferability refers to the degree to which the results of qualitative research can be generalized or transferred to other contexts or settings.** From a qualitative perspective transferability is primarily the responsibility of the one doing the generalizing. The qualitative researcher can enhance transferability by doing a thorough job of describing the research context and the assumptions that were central to the research. The person who wishes to "transfer" the results to a different context is then responsible for making the judgment of how sensible the transfer is. source: https://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/qualval.php